# "The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type Stringchar" error on using charAt method

Tags: java, string, char

```
package Collections;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Stringchar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count =0;
        String s = "mmamma";

        //System.out.println(s.length());

        LinkedHashSet<Character> ch = new LinkedHashSet<Character>(); 
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            ch.add(s.charAt(i));
        }

        Iterator<Character> iterator = ch.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            Character st = (Character) iterator.next();
            for (int k=0; k<s.length() ; k++){
                if(charAt(k)==  st){ // Why this charAt method is not working?   
                    count = count+1;
                }

                if(count>1) {
                    System.out.println("Occurance of "+ st + "is" + count);
                }
            }                           
        }           
    }
}
```

I am new to coding so I might be silly in asking this question. I have written a code where I am trying to print the occurrences and the number of the same of one character in a string using sets however I am facing some issues in doing so. Request you to help.

Comment: Just for the record, as newbies often forget about that: please consider accepting one of the answers at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
charAt(k);
```

is basically the same as

```
this.charAt(k);
```

In other words: you are trying to invoke a method on the class this code sits in.

I assume you intended to do `someStringVariable.charAt(k)` instead! ( sure, you meant `s.charAt()`, but `s` is a terrible, nothing telling name for a variable. Your variables are your pets, give them names that mean something!)

Comment: Yes sure. I will take care of this in future.

Answer (score 0):

The method `charAt` is not static and need to be applied on a given `String`, if not how to know where to look for the xxth char ?

```
str.charAt(index);
```

---

Also, the `print` operation would better be after the `for loop` which counts the occurences, if not you'll have a print at each occurence

```
for (int k=0; k<s.length() ; k++){
    if(s.charAt(k) ==  st){    
        count = count+1;
    }
}
if(count>1) {
    System.out.println("Occurance of "+ st + "is" + count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I corrected this and now I am getting correct results.

Comment: @UjjwalSharma ok so don't hesite to vote up the answers that helped you, and accept one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to check, how often the Character appears in your string (`String s = "mmamma";`).

The `charAt()` method has to be applied on a String object, so you have to change the if condition from this:

```
if(charAt(k) ==  st)
```

To this:

```
if(s.charAt(k) ==  st)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your code like so,

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    int count = 0;

    Character st = (Character) iterator.next();
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
        if (s.charAt(k) == st) { // Why this charAt method is not working?
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println("Occurance of " + st + " is: " + count);
    }
}
```

`charAt` method is available in `String` class hence you have to call it on a `String` reference. I have made few more improvements to the code too. Declare the count variable inside the `while` loop which is less error prone. Finally notice that I have moved the `if` statement away from the `for` loop since it gives some spurious intermediary results if it is kept inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get a character at a position of a character. When you create the variable `st` it is a character and will have a length of 1; there fore you are unable to get a `charAt(index)` there. Additionally this method of using the `LinkedHashSet` will not work because when you add those characters to the `LinkedHashSet` it will not add each character more than once. Instead you want an `ArrayList`.

This is probably not the most efficient solution but it will accomplish what you are trying to do with the `HashSet`

```
String s = "mmamma";

List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashSet<Character> characterLinkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    characterLinkedHashSet.add(c);
    characterList.add(c);
}

for (Character character : characterLinkedHashSet) {
    int frequency = Collections.frequency(characterList, character);
    System.out.println("The frequency of char " + character + " is " + frequency);
}
```

So what this does it is creates your `LinkedHashSet` as well as an `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` stores all of the characters in a `Collection` and the `LinkedHashSet` stores only one instance of each Character. We can then loop over the `HashSet` and get the frequency inside the `ArrayList`